# Link between zero state response and the particular solution for an everlasting exponential input

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis

In an LTI system, when the input is the characteristic function (i.e. an everlasting exponential function say \$e^{st}\$ ), the ZSR which is obtained by the convolution integral with \$h(t)\$ is \$H(s)e^{st}\$, where \$h(t)\$ is the impulse response of the system. Clearly it does not contain any characteristic mode terms. How do these terms get vanished?

Now if I go for the classical approach I get the particular solution for the input \$e^{st}\$ to be \$ce^{st}\$ . The constant c comes out to be \$H(s)\$ and hence I get \$H(s)e^{st}\$  as the particular solution which is same as ZSR. What does it mean, did I commit some error or are they actually equal? With the help of Laplace Transform  I can represent most of the signals in terms of everlasting exponential components. And hence as it follows from the above query, I should get ZSR and PI to be the same for most of the input signals. This can't be true. I'm sure I've gone wrong somewhere. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is any problem with the notation used by the author. He just wanted to express the following (\$x\$ input, \$y\$ output - the response to a eigenfunction \$e^{st}\$):

$$y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)x(t-\tau)d\tau  $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)e^{s(t-\tau)}d\tau  $$
$$ = e^{st} \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)e^{-s\tau}d\tau  $$

Thus, the response to \$e^{st}\$ is of the form

$$y(t) = H(s)e^{st}$$

where \$H(s)\$ is a complex constant whose value depends on \$s\$ and wich is related to the impulse response by

$$ H(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)e^{-s\tau}d\tau  $$

There is no conflict time x frequency here.

Also, note:

If \$\lambda\$ is a pole of \$H(s)\$, the mode \$e^{{\lambda}t}\$ can be generated at the output by an initial state without the application of any input. If \$\lambda\$ is not a pole of \$H(s)\$, then this is not possible. In this case, the only way to generate \$e^{{\lambda}t}\$ at the output is to apply \$e^{{\lambda}t}\$ at the input.  In other hand, if the input \$x(t)\$ is of the form \$e^{{\lambda}t}\$, where \$\lambda\$ is not a pole of \$H(s)\$, then the output due to input \$x(t) = e^{{\lambda}t}\$  is equal to \$y(t) = H(\lambda)e^{{\lambda}t}\$.

Comment: So lets look at it in the at it in the (fully) complex domain, with \$p\$ as complex variable and \$s\$ as a complex constant. \$X(p)=\mathfrak{L}\{e^{st}\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-pt}e^{st} dt\$ and \$X(p)=\int_0^\infty e^{(s-p)t}dt =\frac{1}{p-s}\$. We can define the new complex variable \$z=p-s\$. Therefore \$Y(p)=X(p-s)H(p)\$ or \$Y(z+s)=X(z)H(z+s)\$. So we're having a shift by \$s\$ for \$Y\$ and \$H\$. I'm not sure how to interpret the last equation, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understood what you were asking correctly. You can make the convolution unnecessary by transforming \$e^{st}\$ to the Laplace domain and then doing a simple multiplication. See [Convolution theroem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)

I would suggest that you use \$e^{kt}\$ or something, to not mix it up with the complex variable \$s\$. The response would therefore be \$H(s)\mathfrak{L}\{e^{kt} \}\$ what is \$H(s)\frac{1}{s-k}\$.